Faster way to implement apply()
I am trying to write a general program that involves a general (or user-defined) function h() which outputs a vector-valued function or its derivative (which is a matrix). I need to run this function on every row of a matrix X. Currently, using apply(), I get an output matrix where the outputs of h() are columns of the matrix (the derivative of h(), which is a matrix, are flattened out into vectors). I like the structure of this output of apply(), it is good for my next calculation. However, it is too slow, I wonder if there are faster ways to do this?
h <- function(x, beta = 0, deriv = FALSE) {
  wts <- exp(sum(-x*beta)) + 1
  if (deriv) { #derivative with respect to beta
    ret <- (-1/wts^2)*(-wts+1)*as.matrix(x)%*%t(as.matrix(x)) 
  } else {
    ret <- as.matrix(x*(1/wts))
  }
  ret #return
}

X <- matrix(rnorm(10000), nrow = 10, ncol = 1000)

#these calls are very slow
apply(X = X, 1, function(x) { h(x = x, beta = 1:10, deriv = FALSE)})
apply(X = X, 1, function(x) { h(x = x, beta = 1:10, deriv = TRUE)})



is your actual problem on much larger matrices? these run almost instantaneously for me, i'm guessing solve is the slow part

Try running timing tests on your function h() alone, and compare that (times the number of rows or columns) to the time the apply line takes.    Next,  use the Rprof tool to dive into the guts of all your calls.

Please qualify too slow or very slow. Is it 5 seconds, 5 minutes, or 50 minutes? What timing for you expect?

Save a few cpu cycles and get rid of all calls to as.matrix since with x a vector, x %*% t(x) and as.matrix(x) %*% t(as.matrix(x)) return the same matrix.

The performance issue isn’t the loop. It is needing an R-level loop at all and the function itself. If it needs to work with an arbitrary function there isn’t really a way to make it more performant.

In h the vector x is 1000 long and beta is 10 long yet they are multiplied together.  Is this intended?
